# Is it true that $\frac{n}{2}=\Theta(n)$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

This is probably a very silly question.

If $h(n)=\frac{n}{2}, \ g(n)=n$, so
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{h(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
so $h(n) \leq C_1 g(n), h(n)=O(n)$

at the same time , if $g(n)=\frac{n}{10}$, this limit becomes 5, so

$h(n) \geq C_2 g(n), h(n)= \Omega(n)$

Is this logic correct enough to say that 
$$
\frac{n}{2}=\Theta(n)
$$

Comment: Yes (trivally). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: In general, for any function $f(n)$ and any constant $c$, we have $c f(n) = \Theta(f(n))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes but note that it also immediately follows from the definitions.

Comment: you mean definition of $\Theta(n)$?

Comment: @user19821 yes indeed, it is obvious how you have to choose the constants that it nicely fits the definition.